# turn HTML (heredoc) to valid json using PHP

Tags: php, html, json

let's say I have the following heredoc

```
$content = <<< AF
<div class="authform">
    <form id="auth" class="flex rad" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="auth(this)">
        <div class="input">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" dir="ltr">
            <label for="email" class="flex">
                <div class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#040505" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><rect x="3" y="5" width="18" height="14" rx="2" /><polyline points="3 7 12 13 21 7" /></svg></div>
                <div class="title">email</div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" dir="ltr">
            <label for="pass" class="flex">
                <div class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#040505" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><rect x="5" y="11" width="14" height="10" rx="2" /><circle cx="12" cy="16" r="1" /><path d="M8 11v-4a4 4 0 0 1 8 0v4" /></svg></div>
                <div class="title">pass</div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
</div>
AF;
```

how can I turn it into a valid json string? like `{"content":"<div...."}`

I have tried many things but it does not end up in a valid json!
tried every flag out there but not working

even tried php's "loadHTML" to recreate the html but not working.

this is one of my many attempts

```
    $Obj = new stdClass();

$content = <<< AF
<div class="authform">
    <form id="auth" class="flex rad" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="auth(this)">
        <div class="input">
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" dir="ltr">
            <label for="email" class="flex">
                <div class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#040505" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><rect x="3" y="5" width="18" height="14" rx="2" /><polyline points="3 7 12 13 21 7" /></svg></div>
                <div class="title">email</div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" dir="ltr">
            <label for="pass" class="flex">
                <div class="icon"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#040505" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><rect x="5" y="11" width="14" height="10" rx="2" /><circle cx="12" cy="16" r="1" /><path d="M8 11v-4a4 4 0 0 1 8 0v4" /></svg></div>
                <div class="title">pass</div>
            </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">login</button>
    </form>
</div>
AF;
$content = stripslashes(html_entity_decode($content));
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding(htmlspecialchars($content), 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$atag = $dom->getElementsByTagName('svg');
foreach ($atag as $i) {
    $old = $i->getAttribute('xmlns');
    $i->setAttribute('xmlns', urlencode($old));
}
$ptag = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
$content = html_entity_decode(implode(
    "",
    array_map([$dom, 'saveHTML'], iterator_to_array($ptag->childNodes))
));
$Obj->content = $content;
echo json_encode($Obj, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_ERROR_UTF8 );
```

and this is the output:

```
{"content":"\u003Cdiv class=\u0022authform\u0022\u003E\r\n \u003Cform id=\u0022auth\u0022 class=\u0022flex rad\u0022 enctype=\u0022multipart\/form-data\u0022 onsubmit=\u0022auth(this)\u0022\u003E\r\n \u003Cdiv class=\u0022input\u0022\u003E\r\n \u003Cinput type=\u0022email\u0022 name=\u0022email\u0022 id=\u0022email\u0022 dir=\u0022ltr\u0022\u003E\r\n \u003Clabel for=\u0022email\u0022 class=\u0022flex\u0022\u003E\r\n \u003Cdiv class=\u0022icon\u0022\u003E\u003Csvg xmlns=\u0022http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg\u0022 viewBox=\u00220 0 24 24\u0022 stroke-width=\u00221.5\u0022 stroke=\u0022#040505\u0022 fill=\u0022none\u0022 stroke-linecap=\u0022round\u0022 stroke-linejoin=\u0022round\u0022\u003E\u003Crect x=\u00223\u0022 y=\u00225\u0022 width=\u002218\u0022 height=\u002214\u0022 rx=\u00222\u0022 \/\u003E\u003Cpolyline points=\u00223 7 12 13 21 7\u0022 \/\u003E\u003C\/svg\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\r\n \u003Cdiv class=\u0022title\u0022\u003Eemail\u003C\/div\u003E\r\n \u003C\/label\u003E\r\n \u003C\/div\u003E\r\n \u003Cdiv class=\u0022input\u0022\u003E\r\n \u003Cinput type=\u0022password\u0022 name=\u0022pass\u0022 id=\u0022pass\u0022 dir=\u0022ltr\u0022\u003E\r\n \u003Clabel for=\u0022pass\u0022 class=\u0022flex\u0022\u003E\r\n \u003Cdiv class=\u0022icon\u0022\u003E\u003Csvg xmlns=\u0022http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg\u0022 viewBox=\u00220 0 24 24\u0022 stroke-width=\u00221.5\u0022 stroke=\u0022#040505\u0022 fill=\u0022none\u0022 stroke-linecap=\u0022round\u0022 stroke-linejoin=\u0022round\u0022\u003E\u003Crect x=\u00225\u0022 y=\u002211\u0022 width=\u002214\u0022 height=\u002210\u0022 rx=\u00222\u0022 \/\u003E\u003Ccircle cx=\u002212\u0022 cy=\u002216\u0022 r=\u00221\u0022 \/\u003E\u003Cpath d=\u0022M8 11v-4a4 4 0 0 1 8 0v4\u0022 \/\u003E\u003C\/svg\u003E\u003C\/div\u003E\r\n \u003Cdiv class=\u0022title\u0022\u003Epass\u003C\/div\u003E\r\n \u003C\/label\u003E\r\n \u003C\/div\u003E\r\n \u003Cbutton type=\u0022submit\u0022\u003Elogin\u003C\/button\u003E\r\n \u003C\/form\u003E\r\n \u003C\/div\u003E"}
```

but I get the following trying to parse it using js:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 24"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: like `{"content":"<div...."}` is not much to go on, why not just do https://3v4l.org/9ZApo

Comment: still get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 24"!
https://jsfiddle.net/mhdizmni/o3ubxqtg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put the variable in an associative array and convert it to JSON.

```
$content = <<<AF 
...
AF;
echo json_encode(['content' => $content], JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_FORCE_OBJECT | JSON_ERROR_UTF8);
```

Comment: still get the error
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Expected ',' or '}' after property value in JSON at position 24"! :(

Comment: That can't possibly happen with this.

Comment: I used the output here https://jsfiddle.net/mhdizmni/7r1gnbzv/
still the same error. could you please check?

Comment: The JSON is valid. You need to double all the backslashes when you put the JSON in a string literal.

Comment: It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Lo1jc6fu/

Comment: But none of this should be an issue if you're returning the JSON from an API, it's only when you embed the JSON as a literal in the JS source code.